ничей versus ничьего
In Руслан и Людмила by Pushkin we have:

Еще ничей в его обитель
Не проникал доныне взор;

If I understand well, ничей is a complement of взор and thus ничей should refer to an animate being but I thought that ничей could be used only for inanimate beings and we should use ничьего when we refer to an animate being.

Ничей means "no one's".
It's a pronominal adjective (местоименное прилагательное), and, as such, has to agree in number, case, and gender with the noun it defines (взор). It is true that semantically it only makes sense to define animate beings (or, in this case, the lack thereof) that can turn a gaze, but this fact doesn't manifest itself syntactically.
I guess that the source of your confusion stems from the fact that in English and Italian these constructs are analytic and involve the genitive: "no one's" and di nessuno.
In Russian, however, it's a word in its own right, that parallels the question word: чей "whose"  / ничей "no one's".
